# Как настроить анроид студио под своё расширение экрана?

Tags: android, android-studio

Использую свой смартфон как емулятор... расширение дисплея  540x960 точек!!! Когда запускаю приложение , оно отображается не так как а в layout xml андроид студио (немного смещаются кнопки и прочие view элементы) подозреваю что через другое расширение в визуальном представлении xml. Стандартного расширения  540x960 точек не нашел!!! 
**Подскажите как создать свой дивайс с таким расширением !! ???**

П.С.
Имею ввиду это: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы это приложение только для себя делаете? Больше ни на каких устройствах использовать не планируете? Потому что в противном случае ваше приложение должно безболезненно адаптироваться ко всем размерам экранов.

Comment: @pavlofff, я не указывал отступы с помощью dp, но оно все равно на моем расширении криво отображает !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Откройте AVD и создайте виртуальное устройство с нужным вам **разрешением** экрана, затем выберите его в списке устройств вместо Nexus 5X